# How do I remove white space between link and period in hamlc

Tags: ruby, hamlc

Here is my hamlc code:

```
%a{href: 'http://www.google.com'} hello
\.
```

This results in the following output:

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">hello</a>
.
```

The line break results in a space between the link and the period.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haml has a [whitespace-removal](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_) character `>`. Place it right after your tag to remove surrounding whitespace:

```
%a{href: 'http://www.google.com'}> hello
\.
```

Output:

```
<a href='http://www.google.com'>hello</a>.
```

Comment: How do you force whitespace on the left side?